# Why does racc require a Ruby version >= 2.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I have setup a docker image with Ruby 2.3.4, and have the following error...

```
> [6/9] RUN gem install rails -v 4.2.11.1:                                                                                          
#9 11.36 ERROR:  Error installing rails:
#9 11.36        racc requires Ruby version >= 2.5.
#9 11.38 Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.6
#9 11.38 Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.9
#9 11.38 Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.1.10
#9 11.38 Successfully installed i18n-0.9.5
#9 11.38 Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.11.1
#9 11.38 Successfully installed rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.4
```

This same configuration works happily outside of docker, what have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

You try to install gem rails v.4.2.11

[It uses](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/4.2.11/dependencies) racc 1.6.0

[image]

This racc version [needs](https://rubygems.org/gems/racc/versions/1.6.0) ruby >= 2.5

Usually we install gems with bundler from `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`. And install specific rails version only if need to create new app with it. I don't think you want to create new app with old Ruby and old Rails

So if you have project with such rails version, I think it's better to run `bundle install`. If you have working project with locked gems versions, they will be installed successfully